# Замена Graphics.DrawLine на DrawingContext.DrawLine

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Имеется код, который нормально работает в `WinForms`, но хочется перенести его в `WPF`.

```
static class GraphicsExtension
{
  private static void DrawCubicCurve(this Graphics graphics, Pen pen, float beta, float step, PointF start, PointF end, float a3, float a2, float a1, float a0, float b3, float b2, float b1, float b0)
  {
    float xPrev, yPrev;
    float xNext, yNext;
    bool stop = false;

    xPrev = beta * a0 + (1 - beta) * start.X;
    yPrev = beta * b0 + (1 - beta) * start.Y;

    for (float t = step; ; t += step)
    {
      if (stop)
        break;

      if (t >= 1)
      {
        stop = true;
        t = 1;
      }

      xNext = beta * (a3 * t * t * t + a2 * t * t + a1 * t + a0) + (1 - beta) * (start.X + (end.X - start.X) * t);
      yNext = beta * (b3 * t * t * t + b2 * t * t + b1 * t + b0) + (1 - beta) * (start.Y + (end.Y - start.Y) * t);

      graphics.DrawLine(pen, xPrev, yPrev, xNext, yNext);

      xPrev = xNext;
      yPrev = yNext;
    }
  }

  internal static void DrawBSpline(this Graphics graphics, Pen pen, PointF[] points, float beta, float step)
  {
    if (points == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("The point array must not be null.");

    if (beta < 0 || beta > 1)
      throw new ArgumentException("The bundling strength must be >= 0 and <= 1.");

    if (step <= 0 || step > 1)
      throw new ArgumentException("The step must be > 0 and <= 1.");

    if (points.Length <= 1)
      return;

    if (points.Length == 2)
    {
      graphics.DrawLine(pen, points[0], points[1]);
      return;
    }

    float a3, a2, a1, a0, b3, b2, b1, b0;
    float deltaX = (points[points.Length - 1].X - points[0].X) / (points.Length - 1);
    float deltaY = (points[points.Length - 1].Y - points[0].Y) / (points.Length - 1);
    PointF start, end;

    {
      a0 = points[0].X;
      b0 = points[0].Y;

      a1 = points[1].X - points[0].X;
      b1 = points[1].Y - points[0].Y;

      a2 = 0;
      b2 = 0;

      a3 = (points[0].X - 2 * points[1].X + points[2].X) / 6;
      b3 = (points[0].Y - 2 * points[1].Y + points[2].Y) / 6;

      start = points[0];
      end = new PointF
      (
        points[0].X + deltaX,
        points[0].Y + deltaY
      );

      graphics.DrawCubicCurve(pen, beta, step, start, end, a3, a2, a1, a0, b3, b2, b1, b0);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < points.Length - 2; i++)
    {
      a0 = (points[i - 1].X + 4 * points[i].X + points[i + 1].X) / 6;
      b0 = (points[i - 1].Y + 4 * points[i].Y + points[i + 1].Y) / 6;

      a1 = (points[i + 1].X - points[i - 1].X) / 2;
      b1 = (points[i + 1].Y - points[i - 1].Y) / 2;

      a2 = (points[i - 1].X - 2 * points[i].X + points[i + 1].X) / 2;
      b2 = (points[i - 1].Y - 2 * points[i].Y + points[i + 1].Y) / 2;

      a3 = (-points[i - 1].X + 3 * points[i].X - 3 * points[i + 1].X + points[i + 2].X) / 6;
      b3 = (-points[i - 1].Y + 3 * points[i].Y - 3 * points[i + 1].Y + points[i + 2].Y) / 6;

      start = new PointF
      (
        points[0].X + deltaX * i,
        points[0].Y + deltaY * i
      );

      end = new PointF
      (
        points[0].X + deltaX * (i + 1),
        points[0].Y + deltaY * (i + 1)
      );

      graphics.DrawCubicCurve(pen, beta, step, start, end, a3, a2, a1, a0, b3, b2, b1, b0);
    }

    {
      a0 = points[points.Length - 1].X;
      b0 = points[points.Length - 1].Y;

      a1 = points[points.Length - 2].X - points[points.Length - 1].X;
      b1 = points[points.Length - 2].Y - points[points.Length - 1].Y;

      a2 = 0;
      b2 = 0;

      a3 = (points[points.Length - 1].X - 2 * points[points.Length - 2].X + points[points.Length - 3].X) / 6;
      b3 = (points[points.Length - 1].Y - 2 * points[points.Length - 2].Y + points[points.Length - 3].Y) / 6;

      start = points[points.Length - 1];

      end = new PointF
      (
        points[0].X + deltaX * (points.Length - 2),
        points[0].Y + deltaY * (points.Length - 2)
      );

      graphics.DrawCubicCurve(pen, beta, step, start, end, a3, a2, a1, a0, b3, b2, b1, b0);
    }
  }
}
```

Суть в том , что в `WPF`  не используется `Graphics.DrawLine`, либо я не знаю как. Но можно использовать `DrawingContext.DrawLine`, но не могу понять как. Может кто сталкивался и может подсказать?
Код взят с https://habrahabr.ru/post/116758/

Comment: А вы не берите всякий код откуда попало, и не пытайтесь перенести его буква в букву. Кубический сплайн? Это делается в одну строчку на WPF.

Comment: Как уже сказали, не нужно переводить код построчно, лучше напишите, что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: @VladD Я хочу реализовать метод как в посте, чтобы рёбра не хаотично пересекали друг друга, а было заметно связь между вершинами графа. (Собственно как на картинках в посте)

Comment: @alladuh: В WPF нарисовать Безье-сегмент очень просто: `<Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 10,100 C 100,0 200,200 300,100" />`. Тут (10,100) — начальная точка, (300, 100) — конечная точка, и (100, 0), (200, 200) — промежуточные точки (P1 и P2 на [этой картинке](https://hsto.org/storage/habraeffect/8b/e6/8be6eab2d58fad6cc8c82afdb74c16b2.jpg)). Вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-cubic-bezier-curve).

Comment: @VladD Не натыкался на такое, большое спасибо. Буду пробовать!